# Adding laravel schedule:run cron throws error Command 'app' not found

Tags: laravel, cron, schedule

My project is running on Laravel 5.7.

I am trying to add a cron job to the server by running

```
*  *  *  *  *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/my-project-root/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But this does not seem to work as it returns Command 'app' not found error
on the console.

[cmd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab1vZ.jpg)

Comment: Can you please add the whole error-stack? And some code of your commands?

Comment: Do other `artisan` commands work? Like `php artisan tinker`, or manually running the schedule via `php artisan schedule:run`, etc etc. We need more information here.

Comment: yes @TimLewis other commands work, it is only that recently I realized that we had never run the cron on the server and tried this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

So this is because you are using php to run your root directory. not cd into it.

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/my-project-root/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

or

```
cd /var/www/html/my-project-root/ && /usr/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: still the same, i added the error image to the question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure,  but maybe I was doing it wrong.

I resolved it by adding the cron entry to the server manually.

I just had to edit the crontab using crontab -e